# How do I go about analysing VirusTotal and Hatching Triage's memdumps?

Tags: malware, memory, sandbox, malware-analysis

I normally use volatility to analyse memory dumps, however, in this case it doesn't seem to be working. I get a "Symbol table not found" kind of error, even though I have downloaded and extracted all symbols tables and volatility works fine with other images.

For example, this sample https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/514854ee27e78d3fb56582d782208af889d76eae58bcb05d7e2377bf33b4fde3/behavior. There's a zipped Zenbox memdump. How can I analyse it and see things like process list, network connections, use malscan, etc?

Same file but on Triage: https://private.tria.ge/221017-yg1mtaptyl
How do I analyse those memdump files? If not with volatility then with some other tool with the same functionality.

All I've been able to use with those memdumps so far has been strings and foremost, both with limited results.